# Window background image displays with an echo

Tags: php, css

I have a simple file with a background image.  The image displays with an "echo" or offset of itself on the screen.  The image is a standard JPG file and I have attempted re-uploading the image to ensure it is not corrupt.  Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>OutInMaine</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url('maps/maine3.gif');
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
footer 
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:120px; /* choose any height */
}
</style>
</head>
<body onLoad="moveTo(200,200); resizeTo(600,850);">
<footer>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<br/><p align="right">Region to display: 
<select name="regions" id="regions">
    <option value="Aroostock">Aroostock</option>
    <option value="DownEast/Acadia">DownEast/Acadia</option>
    <option value="Highlands">Highlands</option>
    <option value="Kennebec/Moose River">Kennebec/Moose River</option>
    <option value="Lakes/Mountains">Lakes/Mountains</option>
    <option value="Mid-coast">Mid-Coast</option>
    <option value="Southern">Southern</option>
    <option value="SpecificCity">Specific City</option>
    <option value="Maine" selected="selected">Maine</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</form>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are applying the bg image to the `html` and the `body`. Could that be it?

Comment: What exactly is your question, i dont get it.

Comment: and you say: standard JPG file yet you use a GIF? Do you use the correct file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under my CSS I had

```
html, body
    {background-image:url("maine.gif");}
```

This caused my image to display twice because it loaded in both the HTML section and BODY division.